# Is there a way to automatically keep per-tenant schemas synchronized?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose you create a bug-tracking system, where every customer has their own schema with their own `issues` table. Later, you are asked to add a `priority` column to `issues`.

Is there a way to apply this change to all customer schemas at once? (Preferably without third-party tools.)

Comment: Use a schema migration tool like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) or Flyway

Comment: If your tables [inherit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) from a common parent, then new columns in the parent would be automatically propagated down the hierarchy, though primary/foreign keys on child tables still need to be managed independently